# Rails association works when it doesnt use an instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm getting the strangest error I've seen in Rails so far. In my view, I can print out the email associated with a painting if I find the record directly (e.g. Painting.find(15). But if I try to use an instance variable it errors (e.g @painting).

views/paintings/show.html.erb

```
<%= Painting.find(15).artist.user.email %>  # works
<%= @painting.artist.user.email %> # Error: "undefined method 'user' for nil:NilClass"
```

controllers/paintings_controller.rb

```
def show
  @painting = Painting.find(15)
end
```

Models: "users", "artists", "paintings".

1. A user can be an artist. So a `user has_one artist`.
2. An `artist has_many paintings`.

Comment: Does the problem only occur with associated objects? Have you verified, that the instance variable is correctly assigned in your view (e.g. `@painting.inspect`) is there any gem or other magic that might alter your instance variable (e.g. Draper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add associations. This how they should look like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :artist # it's ok
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user # add this
  has_many :paintings
end

class Painting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
end
```

For me both cases works with this associations.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
def show
  @painting = Painting.find(15).last
end
```

Currently the second one is returning a 1 element array, but in order to call a dependent method, you must specify 1 item.

Comment: Can you post your model associations? One of your associations might be off. If you use plural associations, with singular methods (or vice versa), it will change your expected results.